# SSIS Mail Triggered wrongly

Tags: ssis, etl

i have a SSIS Package which schedule to check in every 10 min for the file,
and Once the file placed in the path, it execute and triggered mail.

The issue is even when file not placed it start sending mail in every 10 min.

How to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this by correcting the code that checks for the file and sends the mail.